# Rails server won't run - uninitialized constant use (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, nameerror

I ran a bundle install and since have not been able to run rails s successfully within terminal. I am new to rails and have tried to find help on this but nobody can explain it to me in the 101 way. What is going wrong - it looks like this is a NameError?

```
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:230:in `block in constantize': uninitialized constant Use (NameError)
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in `each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in `constantize'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/devise-2.2.3/lib/devise.rb:267:in `get'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/devise-2.2.3/lib/devise/mapping.rb:77:in `to'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/devise-2.2.3/lib/devise/mapping.rb:72:in `modules'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/devise-2.2.3/lib/devise/mapping.rb:89:in `routes'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/devise-2.2.3/lib/devise/mapping.rb:156:in `default_used_route'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/devise-2.2.3/lib/devise/mapping.rb:66:in `initialize'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/devise-2.2.3/lib/devise.rb:301:in `new'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/devise-2.2.3/lib/devise.rb:301:in `add_mapping'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/devise-2.2.3/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:208:in `block in devise_for'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/devise-2.2.3/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:207:in `each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/devise-2.2.3/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:207:in `devise_for'
    from /Users/cfictum/Documents/rails_projects/omrails/config/routes.rb:3:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:282:in `instance_exec'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:282:in `eval_block'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:260:in `draw'
    from /Users/cfictum/Documents/rails_projects/omrails/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:26:in `block in updater'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:78:in `call'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:78:in `execute'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:27:in `updater'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:7:in `execute_if_updated'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:66:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/cfictum/Documents/rails_projects/omrails/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/cfictum/Documents/rails_projects/omrails/config.ru:4:in `block in <main>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
    from /Users/cfictum/Documents/rails_projects/omrails/config.ru:1:in `new'
    from /Users/cfictum/Documents/rails_projects/omrails/config.ru:1:in `<main>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:301:in `wrapped_app'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:252:in `start'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Can you post the contents of config/routes.rb (it seems to be mentioned in the error a couple of times, so might be causing problems)?

Comment: Which gems did you add, modify or update prior to the `bundle install` (if any)?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have typed Use instead of use, perhaps in config/routes.rb

Case is important, if it starts with a capital letter then it is a constant, rather than a function.